# Custom variables for reuse in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So, in my idea for a stack, I have a need to create all resources with a certain name, and that will be formed based on the parameters while creating a stack, like this:

```
Param1: blue
Param2: car
```

So, all the resources will be named `blue-car`, and I will need to cross-reference between them in the template. So for instance, there will be a bucket called 'blue-car' and I will be creating Policies and Roles for this bucket.

Can I, in some way, define a custom global variable (or something else with the same effect) that I would be able to reference everytime I need this NAME, or would I have to keep using ugly `!Joins` all the time?

So instead of doing this:

```
Resource: 
  - !Join
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
    - - !FindInMap 
        - Naming
        - BasicPrefix
        - Name
      - '-'
      - !Ref BusinessUnitName
      - !Ref EnvType
  - !Join
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
    - - !FindInMap 
        - Naming
        - BasicPrefix
        - Name
      - '-'
      - !Ref BusinessUnitName
      - !Ref EnvType
    - '/*'
```

I could do this instead:

```
Resource: 
  - !Join
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
    - {$SomethingMoreHandy}
  - !Join
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
    - {$SomethingMoreHandy}
    - '/*'
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I saw your answer and did a little reading but it looks fairly complicated just to save some copy-pasting.

Comment: That's how it works. CloudFormation is a very poor "programing" language. If it does not suite you can use other IoC tools, such as terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that would be for you to develop your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) which would do template source code manipulations for you to achieve what you want.